# WP add_image_size position not working

Tags: wordpress, image-size

Ok, I'm baffled. Setting up image sizes in Wordpress. The image sizes, slugs and names are registering. I've rewritten the thumbnails endlessly. My initial writing of the thumbnails did have an output that seemed to include position. But not the positions I have listed in my function. I have changed the positions over and over again and no change. What am I missing here? Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
add_image_size( 'mobile-accordion-tab', 650, 115, array( 'left', 'top' ) ); // Image crop for mobile accordions
add_image_size ('offers-nav', 322, 322, array('center', 'center' ) ); // Image crop for stateoffers nav
add_image_size ('offers-accordion', 651, 365 ); // Image crop for state offers accordion
add_image_size( 'listicle-thumb', 470, 314, array( 'center', 'center' ) ); // Image crop for listicle post in two column slider
add_image_size ('resorts-accordion', 225, 340, array( 'left', 'center' ) ); // Image crop for resorts horizontal accordion
add_image_size ('header-logo', 110, 65 ); // Image size for header logo
add_image_size ('footer-logo', 135, 77 ); // Image size for footer logo

add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'custom_image_sizes_choose' );
function custom_image_sizes_choose( $sizes ) {
$custom_sizes = array(
    'mobile-accordion-tab' => 'Mobile Accoridon Tab',
    'offers-nav' => 'Offers State Nav Item',
    'offers-accordion' => 'Offers State Accordion',
    'listicle-thumb' => 'Listicle Thumbnail',
    'resorts-accordion' => 'Horizontal Accordion Resort Image',
    'footer-logo' => 'Footer Logo',
    'header-logo' => 'Header Logo',

);
return array_merge( $sizes, $custom_sizes );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the specification [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/), default value of `$crop` parameter is `false`. i think we should give it a `true` value.

please try following code:

```
    <?php
add_image_size( 'mobile-accordion-tab', 650, 115, array( 'left', 'top' ), true ); // Image crop for mobile accordions
add_image_size ('offers-nav', 322, 322, array('center', 'center' ), true ); // Image crop for stateoffers nav
add_image_size ('offers-accordion', 651, 365, true ); // Image crop for state offers accordion
add_image_size( 'listicle-thumb', 470, 314, array( 'center', 'center' ), true ); // Image crop for listicle post in two column slider
add_image_size ('resorts-accordion', 225, 340, array( 'left', 'center' ), true ); // Image crop for resorts horizontal accordion
add_image_size ('header-logo', 110, 65, true ); // Image size for header logo
add_image_size ('footer-logo', 135, 77, true ); // Image size for footer logo

add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'custom_image_sizes_choose' );
function custom_image_sizes_choose( $sizes ) {
$custom_sizes = array(
    'mobile-accordion-tab' => 'Mobile Accoridon Tab',
    'offers-nav' => 'Offers State Nav Item',
    'offers-accordion' => 'Offers State Accordion',
    'listicle-thumb' => 'Listicle Thumbnail',
    'resorts-accordion' => 'Horizontal Accordion Resort Image',
    'footer-logo' => 'Footer Logo',
    'header-logo' => 'Header Logo',

);
return array_merge( $sizes, $custom_sizes );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. No difference with this edit. It crops it one way every time and edits to position in my function make no change to the output.